sobre tkinter soy un rookie y no se porque me da error
def obtener_pelicula_aleatoria(self):
    try:
        api_key = ''
        response = requests.get(f"https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key={api_key}&language=es&sort_by=popularity.desc")
        data = response.json()
        peliculas = data['results']
        pelicula_aleatoria = random.choice(peliculas)
        self.label_resultado.config(text=f"Título: {pelicula_aleatoria['title']}\nID: {pelicula_aleatoria['id']}")
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        messagebox.showerror("Error", f"Ocurrió un error al obtener la película: {e}")

def obtener_anime_aleatorio():
    try:
        api_key = ''
        response = requests.get(
            f"https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/tv?api_key={api_key}&language=es&sort_by=popularity.desc&with_genres=16")
        data = response.json()
        animes = data['results']
        anime_aleatorio = random.choice(animes)
        print(f"Título: {anime_aleatorio['name']}\nID: {anime_aleatorio['id']}")
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print(f"Ocurrió un error al obtener el anime: {e}")

obtener_anime_aleatorio()


Hola Iván, bienvenido a [es.so]. ¿Cuál es el error exactamente? Es importante que agregues la traza completa del mismo a la pregunta, más aún si no proporcionas un [mcve]. Intenta también que le título de las preguntas sea descriptivo del problema también. En el código que muestras interaccionas con dos widgets de tkinter en dos lineas (el resto es  requests) un Label y el messagebox. El código es correcto, sin más contexto y el error en si poco vamos a poder aportar...
